# Add one class in current class with same 3 class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi everyone okay here is my code, I have same three class in one page.

When I'm scroll up, I'm just want current active parent menu that have child class `wrap-dropdown` have class fixed.

```js
var winScrolltop = $(window).scrollTop(),
  up = false,
  newScroll,
  $target = $('.wrap-dropdown'),
  topTarget = $target.offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  newScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if ((newScroll > winScrolltop) && !up) {
    $target.removeClass('fixed');
    up = !up;
  } else if (newScroll < winScrolltop && up) {
    $target.addClass('fixed');
    up = !up;
  }
  winScrolltop = newScroll;
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left"><li id="menu-item-100" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-84 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-100 active"><a href="http://wasser.dev/sanitary-fittings/">Sanitary &amp; Fittings</a>
<div class="wrap-dropdown" style="width: 1339px; left: -285px;"><ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu animated">
    <li id="menu-item-744" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-744"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/sanitary-wares/" class="dropdown-toggle">Sanitary Wares</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu animated" style="padding-left: 22px;">
            <li id="menu-item-526" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-526"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/sanitary-wares/toilet-urinals/">Toilet &amp; Urinals</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-525" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-525" style="float: left;"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/sanitary-wares/basin/">Basin</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-123" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-123"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/" class="dropdown-toggle">Fittings</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu animated mega-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-421" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-421" style="float: left;"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/">FAUCETS</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu mega-menu" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                <li id="menu-item-425" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-425 hasChild"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/collections/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Collections</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu mega-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-517" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-517"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/collections/classic/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Classic</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-518" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-518"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/collections/contemporer/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Contemporer</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-519" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-519"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/collections/exclusive/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Exclusive</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-520" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-520"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/collections/fashion/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Fashion</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-521" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-521"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/collections/minimalist/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Minimalist</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-522" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-522"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/collections/monochrome/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Monochrome</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-426" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-426"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/shower/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Shower</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-424" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-424"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/bath/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Bath</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-427" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-427"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/basin-en/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Basin</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-428" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-428"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/faucets/faucets-kitchen/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Kitchen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-423" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-423" style="float: left;"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/taps/">TAPS</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu mega-menu" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                <li id="menu-item-431" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-431"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/taps/walls/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Walls</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-430" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-430"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/taps/deck/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Deck</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-429" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-429"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/taps/concealed/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Concealed</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-422" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-422" style="float: left;"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/shower-fittings/">SHOWER FITTINGS</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu mega-menu" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                <li id="menu-item-433" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-433"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/shower-fittings/showers/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Showers</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-432" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-432"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/fittings/shower-fittings/jet-shower/" style="text-transform: none; font-weight: normal;">Jet Shower</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-124"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/kitchen/" class="dropdown-toggle">Kitchen</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-746" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-746"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/accessories/" class="dropdown-toggle">Accessories</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-884" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-884"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/sanitary-fittings/others/" class="dropdown-toggle">Others</a></li>
</ul></div>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-99" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-99"><a href="http://wasser.dev/water-heater/">Water Heater</a>
<div class="wrap-dropdown" style="width: 1339px; left: -471.547px;"><ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu animated">
    <li id="menu-item-129" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-129"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/water-heater/single-point/" class="dropdown-toggle">Single Point</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-128" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-128"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/water-heater/multiple-point/" class="dropdown-toggle">Multiple Point</a></li>
</ul></div>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-98" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-98"><a href="http://wasser.dev/water-pump/">Water Pumps</a>
<div class="wrap-dropdown" style="width: 1339px; left: -622.859px;"><ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu animated">
    <li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-135"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/water-pumps/shallow-well-pumps/" class="dropdown-toggle">Shallow Well Pumps</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-134" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-134"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/water-pumps/semi-jet-pumps/" class="dropdown-toggle">Semi Jet Pumps</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-131" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-131"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/water-pumps/deep-well-pumps/" class="dropdown-toggle">Deep Well Pumps</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-132" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-132"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/water-pumps/deep-well-submersible-pumps/" class="dropdown-toggle">Deep Well Submersible Pumps</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-130" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-130"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/water-pumps/booster-pumps/" class="dropdown-toggle">Booster Pumps</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-136"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/water-pumps/submersible-pumps/" class="dropdown-toggle">Submersible Pumps</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-133" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-133"><a href="http://wasser.dev/category/water-pumps/accesories/" class="dropdown-toggle">Accesories</a></li>
</ul></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

The class `fixed` always added to the all three `wrap-dropdown`. How do I make it just add the class fixed in the current active `wrap-dropdown`?

I try using `$(".wrap-dropdown", this).addClass("fixed");` but it's not working.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: How do you distinguish between the three? how do you know which one is active?

Comment: @OmerBonfil It would seem that OP wants to distinguish that based on if it is in the Viewport or not, looking at the code.

Comment: @OmerBonfil nah that's it. So I must added new class active ?

Comment: it appears so, and when it is active, you can target the one with class active.

Comment: oh okay, the active class is in the parent menu. How to check if the parent menu have a active class ? @OmerBonfil

Comment: I'm using this in the if statement but doesn't work `$('#top-menu>li:first-child>a').parent().hasClass('active');` @OmerBonfil

Comment: I need to see the code for the menu, can you edit the post with the HTML of the menu?

Comment: instead of using `$('#top-menu>li:first-child>a').parent().hasClass('active');` use `$('#top-menu>li.active>a')`

Comment: What if more than one are in the viewport at the same time? It might help if you try to explain why you want to do this, what's the end goal

Comment: updated for the html @OmerBonfil

Comment: The end goal is just for user can access the sub menu that wrapped in the wrap-dropdown class. @DarrenSweeney

Answer (score 1):

Case closed I change the target class, here is the code:

```
               var winScrolltop = $(window).scrollTop(),
                    up = false,
                    newScroll,
                    $target = $('#top-menu>li.active>.wrap-dropdown'),
                    topTarget = $target.offset().top;


                $(window).on('scroll', function () {
                    newScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if ((newScroll > winScrolltop) && !up) {
                        $target.removeClass('fixed');
                        up = !up;
                    } else if (newScroll < winScrolltop && up) {
                        $target.addClass('fixed');
                        up = !up;
                    }
                    // $('#top-menu>li.active>.wrap-wdown').parent().hasClass('active');
                    winScrolltop = newScroll;
                });
```

Thanks for your help @omerBonfil